# Tensorflow always gives me the same result while the outputs are normal

Tags: python, tensorflow

I hope you are having a great day!

I recently tried to train a regression model by using TensorFlow and I completed my code by following the instruction in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression).

```
data = pd.read_csv('regret.csv')
max_regret = data['regret'].max()
data['regret'] = data['regret'] / max_regret  # Normalize Regrets

regret_labels = data.pop('regret')

def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(data.keys())]),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    return model

model = build_model()

class PrintDot(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0: print('')
        print('.', end='')

EPOCHS = 1000
# early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100)
history = model.fit(
    data, regret_labels,
    epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0,
    callbacks=[PrintDot()])
test = model.predict(data)
loss, mae, mse = model.evaluate(data, regret_labels, verbose=2)
```

However, I encountered a problem that all the predictions were the same, even though the model.evaluate() gave me different statistics by trials.

[image]

I also attached the file via [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAGPs7NjHt3_KC_Vt6L-M89ygT-2TqVaWX-TLB5JrP0oMGRj1zC0).

Would you take a look at it and give me some ideas to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach as below which split your data set into training and test set before fitting into the model.
You can try this approach as below which split your data set into training and test set before fitting into the model.

```
      import pandas as pd
      import keras
      from keras.models import Sequential
      from keras.layers.core import Dense
      from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

      data = pd.read_csv('regret.csv')
      max_regret = data['regret'].max()
      data['regret'] = data['regret'] / max_regret
      len(data.keys())
      data

      train_dataset = data.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
      test_dataset = data.drop(train_dataset.index)

      train_labels = train_dataset.pop('regret')
      test_labels = test_dataset.pop('regret')

      def build_model():

           model = Sequential()
           model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(27,)))
           model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
           model.add(Dense(1))

      optimizer = RMSprop(0.001)

      model.compile(loss='mse',
                   optimizer=optimizer,
                   metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
      return model

      model = build_model()

      class PrintDot(keras.callbacks.Callback):
           def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
                if epoch % 100 == 0: print('')
                    print('.', end='')

      EPOCHS = 1000

      early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100)
      history = model.fit(
          train_dataset, train_labels,
          epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0,
          callbacks=[PrintDot()])

      test = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

The result have slightly changes as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8RxO.png)

What you could do better is min max scaling all the attributes.

Hope it can help you.